# How to use delomboked sources in gradle build / test?

Tags: java, gradle, lombok

I'm using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) in a gradle based project and the build process requires to delombok the source code before continuing with unit tests or production build. What is the best way to achieve something like that in gradle?

At the moment the generated classes are created in a /build/delombok directory.

The first thought I had was to create a new source set and a task that is based on **compileJava** but if I do this I will probably have to update every other gradle task to depend on my new one. Is this the right approach or is there something better?

I'm using gradle 4.10

Comment: "the build process requires to delombok the source code before continuing" Why?

Comment: I'm trying to compile with aspectj's compiler and lombok doesn't like that. Based on other SO questions, it seems that the solution to that is to delombok the source files first.

Comment: Not an answer, but I'd be a little wary of delomboking, it might be specific to the IntelliJ plugin or might be a fixed bug, but my experience has shown that sometimes delomboking with the intellij plugin at least isn't equivalent - e.g. classes won't even compile anymore. See https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1794

Comment: I'm delomboking through gradle. The process is IDE agnostic.

Comment: Excellent, I was just raising the issue in case the bug is not specific to the IDE plugin, perhaps similar issues can also occur if delomboking via gradle but I'd hope not.